# CSS classes overlapping in an unintended way

Tags: css

What I'm trying to achieve is that when hovering over the td, that the background changes to black and the text color to white, but I only get the black background. I believe this happens because there is an interference with the "blueColor" and "redColor" classes with the "hover:hover" class.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blackBorder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p.redColor {
  color: red;
}

p.blueColor {
  color: blue;
}

.lightGreenBackground {
  background-color: #b5f79e;
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lightGreenBackground blackBorder hover">
      <p class="redColor">1</p>
      <p class="blueColor">H</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried using the !important property without any success and I'm not allowed to use id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you already have a `color` defined on `p` and not `td.hover` means you will have to change the color of `<p>` when `td.hover` is in a `hovered` state.

You'll notice if you remove both colors from your CSS, the text will turn white as expected on hover.

You can target both `p`'s and change the color using `.hover:hover > p`.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.blackBorder {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

p.redColor {
  color: red;
}

p.blueColor {
  color: blue;
}

.lightGreenBackground {
  background-color: #b5f79e;
}

.hover:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.hover:hover > p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lightGreenBackground blackBorder hover">
      <p class="redColor">1</p>
      <p class="blueColor">H</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```